# Sending the keyboard combo RWIN + shift + left with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors, naturallyspeaking

I am trying to write a script that can send the keyboard combo <kbd>RWIN</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> to move the selected window to the monitor to the left, with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting.

<kbd>RWIN</kbd> corresponds to the right windows key:

[image]

I tried:

```
Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As _
Long, bScan As Long, ByVal Flag As Long, ByVal exInfo As Long) As Long
Const VK_RWIN = 92
Sub Main
keybd_event(VK_RWIN,0,0,0)
Wait(.2)
SendKeys "+({Left})"
Wait(.2)
keybd_event(VK_RWIN,0,2,0)
End Sub
```

But this sends <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> followed by <kbd>RWIN</kbd>.

Comment: Ever figure this one out?  Otherwise, I guess you could always do it by autohotkey scripting and then simply calling that script when needed in your  Dragon command.  Or see below.

Comment: @PGilm no :( yes I guess AHK in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add the wait flag to the `SendKeys` instruction.  In that case, separate `Wait` steps may not be needed (and I commented them out).  Try:

```
Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As _
    Long, bScan As Long, ByVal Flag As Long, ByVal exInfo As Long) As Long
Const VK_RWIN = 92

Sub Main
    keybd_event(VK_RWIN,0,0,0)
    ' Wait(.2)
    SendKeys "+({Left})", 1  ' 1 = wait is true
    ' Wait(.2)
    keybd_event(VK_RWIN,0,2,0)
End Sub
```

Hth